# sql update trigger not executing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

I have this trigger on a table named Products, but it does not seem to do anything, regardless of what I set the DiscountPercent value to.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
ON Products
AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    DECLARE @NewData decimal
    IF (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) < 0 AND (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) > 100
BEGIN;
    THROW 50001, 'Please enter a valid discount percent', 1
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
    IF (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) < 1
UPDATE Products
SET DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) * 100
WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM Inserted)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like either SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: for the future i will remember that point, but in this case only one item should be added at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to throw an error if the discount is < 0 **OR** > 100
so this line

```
IF (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) < 0 AND (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) > 100
```

should become this line

```
IF (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) < 0 OR (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Inserted) > 100
```

Edit: You can also try to change the throw for a [raiserror](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

```
RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.', -- Message text.
            10, -- Severity,
            1   -- State
          )
```

Comment: +1: `AND` of course will never be true.  Problematic, however, is that this approach assumes that there is only one row in `inserted`.

Comment: Oh yeah Barry, I think you're right about the multiple rows inserted at once.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using an [EXISTS() statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx).

Second, ensure that all trigger logic use [set-based logic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/30/procedural-versus-set-based-sql.aspx). Otherwise, your trigger will blow up if a user inserts two or more records. I updated your IF and UPDATE statements.

Third, use the [RAISERROR() statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). Only use the [THROW() statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) if you are using SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
ON Products
AFTER UPDATE
AS 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Inserted WHERE DiscountPercent NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR('Please enter a valid discount percent', 16, 10)
    END
    ELSE
        UPDATE Products
        SET DiscountPercent = Inserted.DiscountPercent * 100
        FROM Products
            Join Inserted
            On Products.ProductID = Inserted.ProductID -- IFF ProductID is PK
        WHERE Inserted.DiscountPercent < 1
GO
```